# Visual Indicator in user page of "Highest Voted Answer"

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

On the user page it lists all my answers, and I like seeing the ones that are marked as correct (obviously).

If they are not correct, I'd like to go to the question and fix my answer until it is correct. On some of those questions, it turns out that I have the highest voted answer, but no answer has been selected. In that case, I don't really have any 'extra' improvements to make, I should just wait until the OP chooses to comment or accept an answer.

It would be nice if there was an indication that I have the highest upvoted answer on those questions.

**considerations**

What to do if more than one user has the same number of votes?

What to do if your question is higher upvoted than the 'accepted' answer?

Comment: I just reassure myself that, even if I don't have the *highest-voted* answer, I always have the *best* answer.  It is quite freeing.

Comment: So, what am I to do if we both answer the same question?

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that this will be declined on the basis of database normalization: We'll have to query against all other answers to the question for each of your own answers displayed to determine whether yours is the highest voted.

Comment: I guess you could potentially do a select case on the Max(Score) of a question and if your answer = the max, return true, else return false. I do agree that it would add a lot of usage for not a whole lot of added benefit.

Comment: Other options are: Every user has a list of questions that they are the highest scorer on. Every time a vote is made on a question and it changes the highest scorer, those lists would be updated. That way the information would be stored and not dynamic. But regardless, because I don't have access to the source code, I don't need to be concerned with *how* to implement.